# Getting not found error when trying to access Sharepoint file by path via API

Tags: php, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a sharepoint file by its path via the graph API. I'm following the example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/driveitem?view=odsp-graph-online. When I attempt to get the file, I get a resource not found error. I have confirmed that I have access to the files by getting file IDs from the API and then accessing them that way. I need to get them by the path because the file ID is not exposed in sharepoint.

I'm using the URL that is in the address bar when viewing a file in sharepoint. I take that URL and parse it to get the path and pass that along to the the API. Every file I have tried returns the not found message. Am I not using the correct file path? Is there a better way to get the file path out of sharepoint? Is there any other way to get the file without the ID and path? TIA!

I'm using PHP and cURL to make the requests to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My test demo.

MyDoc is a library and has a folder ParentFolder which contains a file report.xlx

/sites/siteid/drives/driveid/root:/ParentFolder/report.xls